# La etiqueta <base href=""> no funciona en IE

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5, internet-explorer-11

Desplegué la aplicación de angular en modo de producción y en todos los navegadores se muestra excepto en Explorer 11, donde recibo el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'pet' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'pet' at Anonymous function (52.205.249.130/pet/vendor.bundle.js:92228:17)

¿Por qué el tag `<base href="">` no funciona en Explorer?

Comment: ¿El código de la etiqueta es `<base href="">` sin nada en el href?

Comment: Falta incluir un [mcve]

Comment: La etiqueta base es compatble con Explorer, será mejor que amplies tu pregunta y añadas código para ver dónde esta el problema.

Answer (score 1):

La etiqueta `<base href="">`es compatible con Internet Explorer. Como puedes comprobar en la documentación de desarrolladores de Mozilla:

- [Documentación en inglés (Mejor explicado)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)
- [Documentación en español](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/base)

A falta de un ejemplo específico de tu problema, debes tener claro que:

- La etiqueta sólo puede estar situada dentro `<head>`.
- Sólo puede haber una etiqueta `<base>` en tu documento. Si tienes más de una, los navegadores suelen ignorar todas salvo la primera.
- No funciona con rutas relativas, por ejemplo `../../`, por lo menos a partir de **IE 8+**. En este caso, **Chrome** y **Firefox** sí que las soportan. Puede que tu problema se encuentre aquí.

En todo caso, siempre puedes validar tu código con la [herramienta de validación de W3C](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_uri). Podría tratarse de alguna etiqueta mal cerrada, carácter extraño, etc. que trata de forma diferente IE a otros navegadores.

Comment: !doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ejemplo</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" href="assets/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
  
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>

Comment: En base a lo que me dices, creo que es porque dentro del tag base estoy utilizando rutas relativas.

Comment: @Alejo ¿es eso el código que tienes?

Comment: @DanNovek esto no responde a la pregunta. Es demasiado genérico y realmente no aborda el problema que Alejo describe y que parece ser un _bug_ conocido de angular con IE11 (en SO en inglés hay [alguna pregunta sobre esto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48013975/3695983), además de un [bug report abierto en GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18176)).